# WPF - Binding in simple User Control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, binding

My problem is certainly right on my face but I can't see it...

I am building a very simple user control - a 3D ellipse - and I expose two properties: LightColor and DarkColor. I need to bind these properties to the gradient in my user control, but it is not showing any color at all. Here's my usercontrol:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBrushes"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="TestBrushes._3DEllipse"
x:Name="UserControl"
d:DesignWidth="200" d:DesignHeight="200">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Ellipse Name="MainEllipse" Stroke="{x:Null}">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,1.1">
                    <GradientStop Color="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=LightColor}" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=DarkColor}"  Offset="0"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
        <Ellipse Name="TopReflectionEllipse" Stroke="{x:Null}" Margin="38,0,38,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="90">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,0">
                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                            <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <GradientStop Color="#A5FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and here's my code-behind:

```
public partial class _3DEllipse
{
    public _3DEllipse()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Color DarkColor { get; set; }
    public Color LightColor { get; set; }
}
```

If I assign colors as opposed to the binding shown in the code, it works ok, but I want to use the properties I am exposing. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is likely that you aren't notifiying the UserControl of changes made to the value of the DarkColor and LightColor properties.  To do so you'll need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.  The purpose of this interface is to make UI components aware of when the value they're bound to is updated; they subscribe to the PropertyChanged event that is exposed by implementing the interface.

A sample implementation is below, I've left the DarkColor property alone, but it would be updated in the same fashion.

```
public partial class _3DEllipse : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private Color _lightColor;


    public _3DEllipse()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // interface implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Color DarkColor { get; set; }
    public Color LightColor
    {
        get { return _lightColor; }
        set
        {
            // only update value if its changed
            if ( _lightColor == value )
            {
                return;
            }

            _lightColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LightColor");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if ( PropertyChanged == null ) return;

        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just using a DependencyProperty works fine, but you HAVE to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.